# In javascript, how to get the unit (e.g. em or px) from a pixel value (e.g. 2em or 20px)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a function that takes a value as an input for padding, see this simplified example:

```
function createBlocks(container,padding) {}
```

I want the padding parameter to be in any value (em, px, etc). So, I need to be able to extract the value and the unit.

I can extract the value with:
`var paddingVal = parseFloat(padding);`

But I can't figure out how to extract the unit value...

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to convert any length into pixels, or do you want to get the substring with the unit?

Comment: You can't convert a relative length into an absolute length without having something for it to be relative to.

Comment: `padding.match(/\d(\D+)/)[1]` (all non-digit characters after a digit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `.replace()`

```
var paddingVal = parseFloat(padding);
var Newpadding = padding.replace(paddingVal , '');
alert(Newpadding);
```

to be more clear .. may you need to replace spaces first

```
var paddingWithoutSpaces = padding.replace(/\s/g, '+');
var paddingVal = parseFloat(padding);
var Newpadding = padding.replace(paddingVal , '');
alert(paddingVal);
alert(Newpadding);
```

Comment: @Quentin Is the OP asking for convert?? ( So, I need to be able to extract the value and the unit.)

Comment: Converting wasn't an issue (if you're interested, this is the approach I use: http://chrissilich.com/blog/convert-em-size-to-pixels-with-jquery/). The solution that Mohammed-Yousef posted is perfect for my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
function createBlocks(padding) {
    var matches = padding.match(/(\d+)(.+)/),
        value = parseFloat(matches[1]),
        unit = matches[2];

    console.log('value: %d, unit: %s', value, unit);
}

createBlocks('3px'); // value: 3, unit: px
createBlocks('12rem'); // value: 12, unit: rem
```

Answer (score -1):

Here’s a version that works with decimal values too:

```
var getUnitValue = function (valueStr) {
    var result = {};
    result.value = parseFloat(valueStr);
    result.unit = valueStr.substr(('' + result.value).length).trim();
    return result;
};

getUnitValue('80.2 px'); // --> {value: 80.2, unit: "px"}
```